# how to set a constraint to restrict number of relationship of a particular type on a single node

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, constraints

I don't have any idea that how to proceed? I am using Cypher Manual for reference.

Question:
Each CricketTeam node has a relation type HAS_CONTRACT_WITH with Player nodes. While creating Nodes, how to set a constraint to restrict CricketTeam node to have maximum 17 number of Player nodes connected on the basis of HAS_CONTRACT_WITH relation type?

I am using JAVA and neo4J.
I have APOC installed for my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the current schema constraints do not support limiting the number of certain relationship types on a node. While this may change in the future, it is not currently a supported feature.

You can enforce this yourself through the use of triggers, either [provided by your own kernel extensions](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/) or via [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#triggers). You can have these check the degree of the relationship type/direction in question and abort a transaction if this violates your limit.